# Magento 2 Getting error on updating an extension in the Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace, mftf, magento2marketplace

i am getting this error on updating an extension in the magento marketplace.

```
{"tool":"mftfmagento","status":"FAIL","reports":[{"php_version":"7.3","magento_platform":"M2","magento_edition":"ce","magento_version":"2.3.6-p1","tool":"mftfmagento","vendor":"tekglide","extension":"freegifts","version":"1.0.1","platform":"m2","magento_cloud_docker":"1.2.1","status":"FAIL","date":"2021-04-28T13:55:47Z","details":{"exit_code":1,"commands":[{"command":"composerConfigRepository0","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code."},{"command":"composerConfigKeys0","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code."},{"command":"echo \"127.0.0.1 magento2.docker\" >> \/etc\/hosts","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"\"."},{"command":"docker-compose -f docker-compose-mftf.yml down --volumes","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"\"."},{"command":"docker-compose -f docker-compose-mftf.yml up --detach --no-color","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"10.2: Pulling from library\/mariadb\nDigest: sha256:187b02ad495b0cc95662f3382bf8a811319b54d224bd12d24919988137de7cb9\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/library\/mariadb:10.2\n5.0: Pulling from library\/redis\nDigest: sha256:12664f201c777d41247ec863bf92cb8145381c0de4fcabfb58f3c61f6ff2dd3e\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/library\/redis:5.0\n7.7-1.2.1: Pulling from magento\/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch\nDigest: sha256:b6a5e3561ec1fc72d40b58f471740aa0e8f4317d71052f2dbf3dc919dcca290b\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/magento\/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch:7.7-1.2.1\n7.3-fpm-1.2.1: Pulling from magento\/magento-cloud-docker-php\nDigest: sha256:fc6a5d652bda6549f1701d53222532a0b76aa1bbf807436439954061e7c03535\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/magento\/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.3-fpm-1.2.1\n1.19-1.2.1: Pulling from magento\/magento-cloud-docker-nginx\nDigest: sha256:7545101b25733542dce7c71fcf1f86ed26bcb581b4d431735796399a0153ca75\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/magento\/magento-cloud-docker-nginx:1.19-1.2.1\n6.2-1.2.1: Pulling from magento\/magento-cloud-docker-varnish\nDigest: sha256:d07c8c303829c7c9bae687c460a560080f6cdc30d4761cc11651c8a3bf053075\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/magento\/magento-cloud-docker-varnish:6.2-1.2.1\nlatest: Pulling from selenium\/standalone-chrome\nDigest: sha256:8d0915d29d5fa495256bda78371cb5adb70fd16ec9e4b4aaae72a0181682f5f0\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/selenium\/standalone-chrome:latest\n7.3-cli-1.2.1: Pulling from magento\/magento-cloud-docker-php\nDigest: sha256:4ca09b4ee9633d51556418eeb7261b01911000d7f25656c7b36dbf3c73f2f40c\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/magento\/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.3-cli-1.2.1\nlatest: Pulling from mailhog\/mailhog\nDigest: sha256:8d76a3d4ffa32a3661311944007a415332c4bb855657f4f6c57996405c009bea\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for 126150169089.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\/mailhog\/mailhog:latest\n\"."},{"command":"docker-compose -f docker-compose-mftf.yml run --rm build composer require --no-ansi tekglide\/freegifts:1.0.1","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"composer\/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...\ncomposer\/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class\nStarting schema dist file generation\nDist file was successfully generated: \/app\/.magento.env.md\n\"."},{"command":"docker-compose -f docker-compose-mftf.yml run --rm build cloud-build","output":"Finished with the \"0\" exit code. Process output: \"Cleaning directories:\nCleaning setup directory.\nCleaning vendor directory.\nCleaning generated directory.\nRemoving app\/etc\/env.php file\nInstalling dependencies.\ncomposer\/
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting almost the same errors. Did you find a solution on this problem?

Comment: No I havent found any solution to this problem. :/